# Quartz.Net ASP.NET Status update

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net

I'm using quartz in an asp.net site and I'm using it to fire off a longer background task. I want to be able to use a timer or jquery to call the job and get back status and progress info similar to how I was doing it before. Here is code that I was using:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (MyTaskManager.Instance.IsTaskRunning)
    {
         if (MyTaskManager.Instance.TotalItems > 0) ProgressLabel.Text =   string.Format(ProgressLabel.Text, MyTaskManager.Instance.TotalItems, MyTaskManager.Instance.ItemsProcessed);
                    else ProgressLabel.Text = string.Format("Records Processed: {0}", MyTaskManager.Instance.ItemsProcessed);
    }
    else
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Has anyone done this that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be what you're looking for but I've used [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) with Quartz.Net and it works great.
I've published a simple application in my [repository](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetQuartSignalR).

You have to create a custom [Hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub(v=vs.118).aspx) which you will use to interact with your ASP.NET page.
Your (**quartz.net**) job will interact your ASP.NET page through your **Hub** the same way.

Once you have installed **ASP.NET SignalR**:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

You can create a startup class to configure SignalR:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AspNetQuartSignalR.Startup))]

namespace AspNetQuartSignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

You have to reference a couple of scripts in your page:

1. jquery-2.1.1.js
2. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js

and the automatically generated **/signalr/hubs**

Now you can create your own [Hub](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetQuartSignalR/blob/master/AspNetQuartSignalR/Hubs/QuartzHub.cs):

```
public class QuartzHub : Hub
{
   ...
}
```

with methods which will allow you to interact with the scripts in your ASP.NET page.

Let's say your **Hub** has a method `CheckQuartzStatus` which gives you the status of all the quartz.net triggers configured:

```
public void CheckQuartzStatus()
{
    string message = string.Empty;

    var allTriggerKeys = Global.Scheduler.GetTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher<TriggerKey>.AnyGroup());
    foreach (var triggerKey in allTriggerKeys)
    {
    ITrigger trigger = Global.Scheduler.GetTrigger(triggerKey);
    message += string.Format("{0} = {1}", trigger.Key, Global.Scheduler.GetTriggerState(trigger.Key)) + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    Clients.All.onCheckQuartzStatus(message);
}
```

Your **jQuery** script can interact with this method in a very simple way:

```
quartz.server.checkQuartzStatus();
```

As you can see your **Hub** method at some point fires an action: **onCheckQuartzStatus**.
That is a call to an event defined in your **javascript** defined in the page :

```
quartz.client.onCheckQuartzStatus = function (message) {
    alert(message);
};
```

You can see how the interaction works looking at the script in the [Default.aspx](https://github.com/Leftyx/AspNetQuartSignalR/blob/master/AspNetQuartSignalR/Default.aspx) page.

You can read a lot more [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to build all of this functionality yourself. Quartz.Net jobs run in the threadpool and you don't have a way of referencing them from the scheduler. You could do this by having the job write its progress somewhere and then have your timer check that spot for progress.